# Website not scaling correctly unless using developer tools

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a web app with many animations that need to remain unchanged. So to make the site responsive I have been using the following code:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 720px) {
    html {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    transform: scale(.5);

    }
 }
```

```html
<div style="width: 700px; height: 700px; background-color: green;"></div>
```

(Best to view snippet in full page)

When the browser is normally displaying the code and I resize it, nothing happens, but when I go into developer tools and use the mobile responsive version, all of a sudden the scaling is working.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the media query detects the size of the ***screen***, not the size of the viewport/browser window. If you go to Dev Tools and resize it, it modifies the query's view of the screen, and makes the code think the screen is a mobile size. Resizing the browser window doesn't have this effect.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, I understand now. Is there a way to do it so that it is based on the browser width? (without having to use values like 100vw/100vh for each individual element). Just a global scale of the page